# X has an exponential distribution. Calculate probability

Tags: probability, statistics

X has an Exp(1) distribution, i.e., f(x) = e^
−x
for x > 0.

(a) Compute the probability that X is within 2 standard deviations of its mean.
(b) Compute the probability that X is within 3 standard deviations of its mean

Answer (score 1):

The exponential distribution is $$f(x)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$$
And it has mean and standard deviation of   $(1/\lambda)$. Which is this case is $1$.

So compute (a) using $$\int_0^3xe^{-x}dx$$
And compute (b) using $$\int_0^4xe^{-x}dx$$
Note that at $x<0$ the value of the probability density function is 0

Comment: First one has an answer $1-4/e^3$, and second one is $1-5/e^4$.